# Comunicação entre o Code Behind e ViewModel Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Tenho duas páginas criadas no `Xamarin.forms`, na primeira página tenho uma lista e na segunda os detalhes de cada item selecionado anteriormente. Eu envio o item selecionado da primeira página pra segunda através da comunicação dos dois *code behind*.

**Página onde tenho a lista(Code Behind):**

```
private async void ListViewCats_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var SelectedCat = e.SelectedItem as Models.Cat;
            if (SelectedCat != null)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.DetailsPage(SelectedCat));
                ListViewCats.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        }
```

**Página de Detalhes(Code Behind):**

```
Cat SelectedCat;
public DetailsPage(Cat selectedCat)
{
    this.SelectedCat = selectedCat;
}
```

Dessa forma consigo exibir os dados desse objeto normalmente no `xaml`. Porém quero passar esse valor `selectedCat` para a `ViewModel` de detalhes que criei, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu passei por uma situação semelhante, eu tinha 4 pages que juntas preenchiam uma mesma entidade (de pedidos), a solução que utilizei na época foi de salvar os dados de cada página em um txt e ir resgatando na próxima página. É bem simples de se fazer, você só precisa tomar cuidado de deletar o arquivo quando não for mais utiliza-lo.

Claro que existem outros meios (como [este](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/53114/xamarin-forms-mvvm-how-to-pass-parameter-to-detail-viewmodel)), tudo depende de como você vai querer fazer.

Caso queira tentar, você vai utilizar o Newtonsoft.json e a System.io.

Para salvar texto:

```
public void SaveText(string filename, string text)
    {
        var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);
    }
```

Para carregar o texto:

```
public string LoadText(string filename)
    {
        var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        else return string.Empty;
    }
```

Métodos da viewmodel:

```
    private void SalvarTxtPedido()
    {
        string ped = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_Ped);
        _SaL.SaveText("Pedido.txt", ped);
    }


public bool CarregaArquivoPedido()
    {
        if (_SaL.ValidateExist("Pedido.txt"))
        {
            _Ped.CardCode = SelectedParceiro.Value.CardCode;
            _Ped.CardName = SelectedParceiro.Value.CardName;

            string jsonPedido = _SaL.LoadText("Pedido.txt");
            _Ped = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ped>(jsonPedido);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou analisar o Link acho meio trabalhoso criar um txt pra fazer uma manipulação pequena

Comment: Blz, se for útil, marque como resposta. Sua dúvida pode ser a mesma de outros.

Answer (score 1):

Eu executo esta operação de uma forma mais simples.
Você pode utilizar o plugin [SettingsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) (*também encontrado nos pacotes nuget no Visual Studio*) e simplesmente "setar" o valor em uma variável e então resgata-lá de onde você quiser.

Criação da variável:

```
private const string UserNameKey = "username_key";
private static readonly string UserNameDefault = string.Empty;

public static string UserName
{
  get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault<string>(UserNameKey, UserNameDefault); }
  set { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue<string>(UserNameKey, value); }
}
```

No seu code-behind onde se encontra o List, quando houver o click, basta:

```
Classe.UserName = "seu item clicado";
```

Na sua outra ViewModel ou em outro code-behide, basta receber o valor.

```
var suaVariavel = Classe.UserName;
```